# Как опустить риски в word

Tags: ms-word

Как в графике Word опустить риски?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы бы указали, как вообще там график делается. И что за "риски"?

Comment: @Сергей рисочки под графиком, я могу поставить метки внизу графика а риски не переносятся или я не понимаю как их передвинуть